# CodeIgniter - Error Message: Undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code where data is being defined as far as I can see, these are the errors I am getting:

> PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: empdata
>
> Filename: views/employee.php
>
> Line Number: 51**
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\providentfund\application\views\employee.php
>   Line: 51
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\providentfund\application\libraries\BaseController.php
>   Line: 99 Function: view
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\providentfund\application\controllers\Employee.php
>   Line: 19 Function: loadViews
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\providentfund\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

controller:

```
      public function display_all()
      {
          $result=$this->Employee_model->display_all();
          $data['empdata']=$result;
         $this->loadViews("employee", $this->global, NULL);

      }
```

model:

```
      function display_all()
      {
      $query=$this->db->query("select * from employetbl");

      return $query->result();
      }
```

and the view:

```
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php
              $cnt=1;

              foreach($empdata as $rec)
              {
                print_r($empdata);
                die();
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $rec['fullName'];?></td>

              </tr>
              <?php
              // for serial number increment
              $cnt++;
              } ?>
```

Why do I get Error Message *"undefined variable"*?

Comment: The problem is how you load the views, it should be done like this instead: `$this->load->view('employee', $data);`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your controller:

```
public function display_all()
      {
          $result=$this->Employee_model->display_all();
          $data['empdata']=$result;
         $this->loadViews("employee", $this->global, NULL);

      }
```

You are calling the loadViews with $this->global but your "empdata" is not defined there.

You should try changing this:

```
$this->loadViews("employee", $this->global, NULL);
```

To this:

```
$this->loadViews("employee", $data, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
public function display_all(){
     $result=$this->Employee_model->display_all();
     $data['empdata']=$result;
     $this->load->view('employee',$data);
}
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
public function display_all()
      {
          $result=$this->Employee_model->display_all();
          $data['empdata']=$result;
         $this->loadViews("employee", $data);

      }
```

In model

```
function display_all()
      {
      $query=$this->db->query("select * from employetbl");

      $result = array();
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $value) {
            $res['variable_name'] = $value['column_name'];
            array_push($result, $res);
        }
        return $result;
      }
```